# How to get log from remote JMeter Node (jmeter-server)?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I'm very new to JMeter and I got a problem - I wasn't able to get jmeter log if I'm using JMeter with remote Node.

I'm starting JMeter by Maven plugin, command looks like:

```
jmeter -n -t my_settings.jmx -l my_result.jtl -r -R <IP_OF_REMOTE_NODE> -X
```

and on the remote node I'm starting jmeter server by command like:

> ./jmeter -Djava.rmi.server.hostname= -Dserver_port=1099 -s

in the logs of our product and in the logs of JMeter I see that the testing is going correctly, but in this case 'my_result.jtl' file is empty, I was expecting that remote node should send the logs back and 'master' should put it to 'my_result.jtl', it seems I got something wrong.

Could you please advise - is it possible in my case to get *jtl report from remote node? Or at least point for remote node where to put the *jtl report.

The last message in the jmeter log (not jtl) of 'master' node (from which I'm running mvn plugin) is:

> jmeter.JMeter: Remote engines have been started

Comment: What version of the plugin are you using?  I think this didn't work correctly before 1.9.0.

Comment: When are you looking at the file? The default mode with which Load Generators send results to the Controller is Batch_Stripped. If the default is still set, you won't see results in that file for a little while- not until the Load Generator has a _batch_ of results. Look at [sending modes](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#sendermode) for more info on sending modes.

Answer (score 0):

When we run with distribution mode, on the master we have to wait "some time" to let all slave send the result back the master.

"some time" at here is:
 1. when we reach to 100 samples (requests) on slave, then slave will send back a result one time. 
 2. Or when we reach 60000ms.

Please check the document at here: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html (13.5 Using a different sample sender - Batch mode)

Answer (score 0):

Is possible to check master node's aggregate report on gui mode ?
Cause when i run my tests on GUI i can see the slave's results simultaneously.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).